# Can I combine view functions in one view class?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Below I have included two view functions that I am currently working with. I was thinking that since both functions operate on the same template that it would be wise to combine them. Can i just put a class decorator above these functions? Is the functionality then still the same?

My main point is that one function only takes 'request' but the other takes 'request and 'slug' in its function.

`choose`

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def choose(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST.get)

        # Make a shoplist model instance,
        # define title,
        # define user as author,
        # define slug,
        # save budget value from the Budget view
        # save dagen value from the Budget view
        # save shoplist

        shoplist = Shoplist()
        shoplist.title = str(make_aware(datetime.now(), timezone=None, is_dst=None))
        shoplist.author = request.user
        shoplist.slug = slugify(str(shoplist.author) + '-' + shoplist.title)
        shoplist.budget = request.POST.get('budget')
        shoplist.dagen = request.POST.get('dagen')
        shoplist.vegetarisch = request.POST.get('vegetarisch')
        shoplist.save()

        # Get recipes from database and POST data form previous view
        if request.POST.get('vegetarisch') == 'True':
            recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(vegetarisch=True).all()
        else:
            recipes = Recipe.objects.all()
        budget = shoplist.budget
        dagen = shoplist.dagen
        template = loader.get_template('recipes/choose.html')
        c = {'object_list': recipes, 'budget': budget, 'dagen': dagen}
        return HttpResponse(template.render(c))

    else:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed('GET')
```

and `add_to_shoplist`

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def add_to_shoplist(request, slug):

    # Get the shoplist that is made in the choose view and add the selected recipe
    latest_list = Shoplist.objects.filter(author=request.user).latest('id')
    current_recipe = Recipe.objects.filter(slug=slug).get()
    latest_list.recipes.add(current_recipe.id)

    # Add the ingredients of the selected recipe to the shoplist
    for ingredient in current_recipe.ingredients.all():
        list_ingredient = ingredient
        latest_list.ingredients.add(list_ingredient.id)

    ingredients = current_recipe.ingredients.all()
    template = loader.get_template('recipes/choose.html')

    if Shoplist.objects.filter(author=request.user).latest('id').vegetarisch == True:
        recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(vegetarisch=True).all()
    else:
        recipes = Recipe.objects.all()
    c = {'object_list': recipes, 'ingredient_list': ingredients}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(c))
```

Comment: as i can see you use different contexts for one template, so it looks like you better use two template with [extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#templates), imho.

Comment: So don't make it class based but I give both functions a different extend?

Comment: I haven't found out yet how I want to solve this problem but I have come to the conclusion that I need to use multiple view functions and somehow generate multiple templates/extends that can be displayed on the same page.